# How do you use the pause assembly instruction in 64-bit C++ code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86, intrinsics, visual-c++-2010

Since inlined assembly is not supported by VC++ 2010 in 64-bit code, how do I get a `pause` x86-64 instruction into my code? There does not appear to be an intrinsic for this like there is for many other common assembly instructions (e.g., `__rdtsc()`, `__cpuid()`, etc...).

On the why side, I want the instruction to help with a busy wait use case, so that the (hyperthreaded) CPU is available to other threads running on said CPU (See: [Performance Insights](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-insights-to-intel-hyper-threading-technology/) at intel.com). The `pause` instruction is very helpful for this use case as well as spin-lock implementations, I can't understand why MS did not include it as an intrinsic.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wow, this was a very hard problem to track down, but in case anybody else needs the x86-64 `pause` instruction:

The `YieldProcessor()` macro from `windows.h` expands to the undocumented `_mm_pause` intrinsic, which ultimately expands to the `pause` instruction in 32-bit and 64-bit code.

This is completely undocumented, by the way, with partial (and incorrect for VC++ 2010 documentation) for [YieldProcessor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687419(v=vs.85).aspx) appearing in MSDN.

Here is an example of what a block of YieldProcessor() macros compiles into:

```
    19:     ::YieldProcessor();
000000013FDB18A0 F3 90                pause  
    20:     ::YieldProcessor();
000000013FDB18A2 F3 90                pause  
    21:     ::YieldProcessor();
000000013FDB18A4 F3 90                pause  
    22:     ::YieldProcessor();
000000013FDB18A6 F3 90                pause  
    23:     ::YieldProcessor();
000000013FDB18A8 F3 90                pause
```

By the way, each pause instruction seems to produce about a 9 cycle delay on the Nehalem architecture, on the average (i.e., 3 ns on a 3.3 GHz CPU).

Comment: Unfortunatly MS 'forgets' to document quite a few functions, which is quite annoying(especially when `__yield` is documented). Some times it a good idea just to comb over intrin.h looking for names similar to what your after(this is how I found `_mm_pause`, though that macro of yours seems way better for portability, +1)

Comment: __yield may be documented, but it only works on IA64 (i.e., not any architecture people actually use :) ). I actually was quite happy when I discovered it, only to find out that it is #ifdefed out for x86/x86-64 builds.

Answer (score 11):

The [`_mm_pause()` intrinsic is fully documented by Intel](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=4067,602,2978,4071,3884&techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,Other&text=pause) and supported by all the major x86 compilers portably across OSes.  IDK if MS's docs were lacking in the past, or if you just missed it ~7 years go.

`#include <immintrin.h>` and use it.  (Or for ancient compilers `#include <emmintrin.h>` for SSE2).

```
#include <immintrin.h>

void test() {
    _mm_pause();
    _mm_pause();
}
```

compiles to this asm on all 4 of gcc/clang/ICC/MSVC ([on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5AHoZ3AMx4WyBiKwBqDgoDCmALb7lBYsoB0Cbdg0a5G4MmQAWM7Q0B3EgGtBHwgg0CBDxBDgAGAEFwqK4lFTVNbR08Q2NTFgsraOiAN1Q8dEDMQQIIAEotAHY%2BSJsbAH1DeoAHJhFBTHLtGoi6jUb9FraOroUejkqAEWipMsZpAFYpUhZpMOXUaR1%2Bfg1hMQktWNplgjXZua8QJ1ozJzDaStoANgAOAE5Kp2euBYV5qROZb6OhhMIrc6kTZSZaCEDgs5SdZzOCwGCIFCofTNPAMTBkCgQNDY3H4kDAV5cUgAM1xBHxcIgACNIUzlExiABPaQnUjE/SYFgEADyLAY3KRyyw%2BlYwDxkPwxEwyAIeByxUhmAAHsqRPSectjJgGJCTCkDXNmGwUDteIw8Ey4ZA5qhmqrUCw4VIALRa5Aab3ChQBgDqTAYDFhonEklolsWy1Wkqh0i1r2e3ueTnsjg0rzMXA0EFwhBIRwU9A0OixOLxxHLcartp4p3OZUuIFid3etDCb1eTkqz2e72%2BlQBQNIIIWtycM7ntAXS4WEOT0Nh8NIiORpFRGOJtfx5EoB9JxBAeEctFeNLpDMoLOTbJYHIlvP5gpFYol61I0tl8rJoqyqquqXq/tqur6lIvJGiayZmiCMGzIwso2rw/D2o68Aum6eAel63olOg2iTMALAiM2i4BkGobhpGQjRhIdDxlISyrr%2B0JphmWYaJe/rXmYYRCUWJZEPWiiVtWJJ1uWXAVNsGG8K2krthOwLXPmCxOK82m6TpekLCuSacdIG4Im2HZcPmA6VAsbxcGCYSVGECxDgCCiJpC65bm2u7onuEBIKedbHkSNZnigDC0O89RZreDD0sQjKPr%2Bz6vgafJYgKQqiuKCoGABkhAXgSoqmqGrJpByB6sVsFCsapqmEhJyWmhnBKQIDAOk65RQnhBHSIGWpRgcsasexJkbKm6aZtmACyADKABqOgaDFGiOY8GgAEoACohqJ%2BDiQ2pBVhFsmKAoCnNipyJzAgmBMFg559VcXDvGYdnOYu7xhFw3xvO8/zwZO04uLQ2mQzcUOw88HHTTCQibtuKGBcFF1HoSIVkqosrPGCCVJSlrLslymUfrl34FTKbCAb%2BwHlWBmo6jV0H1fS8G/ohFqodaHV8Ha3XYc6/Xup6Q20d6YYRqNMYsQCk3eTNPHZnjbAaM8QkicWx1lpJZ3SYeEmxE4N2dXdFykI9z1kn1oMaXOZgDgsLtu3OA5OAjKZI3CFmqVZn3fU8Th/QDw4fCD0ied7Pmo2p8FcF5a5mb5AekOqyX4asThAA%3D)):

```
test():                               # @test()
    pause
    pause
    ret
```

On CPUs without SSE2, it decodes as `rep nop` which is just a `nop`.  [Cross-platform implementation of the x86 pause instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779569/cross-platform-implementation-of-the-x86-pause-instruction)

Gcc even knows this, and still accepts `_mm_pause()` when compiling with `-mno-sse`.  (Normally gcc and clang reject intriniscs for instructions that aren't enabled, unlike MSVC.)  Amusingly, gcc even emits `rep nop` in its asm output, while the other three emit `pause`.  They assemble to same machine code, of course.

---

Pause idles the front-end of that hyperthread for about 5 cycles on Sandybridge-family until Skylake.  On Skylake, Intel increased it to ~100 cycles to save more power in spin-wait loops and increase overall throughput at the possible expense of latency, especially on Hyperthreaded cores.

On all CPUs it also avoids memory-order mis-speculation when leaving a spin-loop.  So it does reduce latency right when it finally matters again.

See also [What is the purpose of the "PAUSE" instruction in x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894078/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-pause-instruction-in-x86/12904645).