# Intel's PAUSE instruction and possible memory order violation

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, busy-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pause instruction in x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894078/pause-instruction-in-x86)

Intel's [Optimization Reference Manual](http://www.intel.co.uk/content/dam/doc/manual/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf) has the following to say about spin-wait loops:

> **3.4.1.2  Spin-Wait and Idle Loops**
>
> The Pentium 4 processor introduces a new PAUSE instruction; the instruction is 
>   architecturally a NOP on Intel 64 and IA-32 processor implementations.
>
> To the Pentium 4 and later processors, this instruction acts as a hint that the code 
>   sequence is a spin-wait loop. Without a PAUSE instruction in such loops, the Pentium 
>   4 processor may suffer a severe penalty when exiting the loop because **the processor 
>   may detect a possible memory order violation.** Inserting the PAUSE instruction 
>   significantly reduces the likelihood of a memory order violation and as a result 
>   improves performance

I am trying to understand the highlighted portion: *the processor 
may detect a possible memory order violation*. Could you explain what this means? In what circumstances could such a violation arise in a busy loop, and why does using `PAUSE` help? Would the violation be real or spurious, and what would be the consequences of not avoiding it?

A example illustrating the problem would be great.

Comment: Indeed, looks like a duplicate of that question, and that question already has an answer that's IMO very detailed and helpful. Hopefully the OP will think so too. :)

Comment: Yeah, that's a great answer. Pity I didn't find that other question before creating my own.